# Unable to print the function value in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, es6-class

I am unable to print the bmi value.  Tried with function call and tried  printing by calling the class object, it is printing empty. Not sure where I am going wrong

```js
var mark = {
  name: 'Mark',
  mass: 25,
  height: 1.62,
  bmi: function() {
    this.finalbmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
    return this.finalbmi;
  }
}


mark.bmi();
console.log(mark);
```

Comment: `console.log(mark.bmi())` or `console.log(mark.finalbmi)`

Comment: Also `return this.finalbmi.toFixed(2);`

Comment: it is very weird that i printed in this order  
console.log(mark.bmi());
console.log(mark);

it works if i switch 
console.log(mark);
console.log(mark.bmi());

it does not work

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the entire object, just print the BMI. Difference is the `.finalbmi` part.

```js
var mark = {
  name: 'Mark',
  mass: 25,
  height: 1.62,
  bmi: function() {
    this.finalbmi = this.mass / (this.height * this.height);
    return this.finalbmi;
  }
}

mark.bmi();
console.log(mark.finalbmi);
```

Or you could print the return value of the function, which is the same and saves a line of code:

```js
console.log(mark.bmi());
```

Answer (score 2):

consoling `mark` will give the function body. You need to get the return of the function but not the object

```js
var mark = {
  name: 'Mark',
  mass: 25,
  hieght: 1.62,
  bmi: function() {
    this.finalbmi = this.mass / (this.hieght * this.hieght);
    return this.finalbmi;
  }

}
const val = mark.bmi();
console.log(val);
```

Comment: How do i print the entire object   also i noted it is very weird that i printed in this order  
console.log(mark.bmi());
console.log(mark);

it works if i switch 
console.log(mark);
console.log(mark.bmi());

it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you just need to console.log(mark.finalbmi);?

Comment: Both result in the same

Comment: Yes, but mark.bmi() is what you are supposed to call

Comment: There is a function to return the bmi implemented in the object. It should of course be on the prototype and not on every person object. The finalbmi should also be a private member and have the public method used as interface to the member. Also to get at finalbmi you would need to first execute and then display instead of executing and display in one go

Comment: it is very weird that i printed in this order  
console.log(mark.bmi());
console.log(mark);

it works if i switch 
console.log(mark);
console.log(mark.bmi());

it does not work, can some one explain why this behaviour

Comment: I assume this happens because, when you first execute mark.bmi(), the mark.finalbmi gets defined, but if you do it the other way around, you're outputting the mark object before defining its .finalbmi property value with the execution of mark.bmi();. You see?